# How to select UITableViewCell using function, without tapping it?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I am populating my tableView using below mentioned array. If user searches an array and item is found then that cell should be selected.

```
    (
        {
        barcode = 8901058847857;
        image =         (
        );
        name = "Maggi Hot Heads";
        productTotal = "60.00";
        quantity = 3;
    },
        {
        barcode = 8901491101837;
        image =         (
        );
        name = "Lays Classic Salted";
        productTotal = "20.00";
        quantity = 1;
    }
)
```

I am using below mentioned code to search barcode in array but I don't know how to proceed further, how to select tableViewCell in else case.
There is code written in tableViewCell setSelected.

```
let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "barcode contains[c] %@",code)
    let filteredArray = orderDetailsArray.filter { namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0) }
    if filteredArray.isEmpty {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Item not found in cart.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:  { action in
            self.scan()
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        print("item found")
        // Need to do selection here
   }
```

Comment: You can simply make array of String that contains filtered barcode and compare that array in cellForRow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else{
        print("item found")
        1. add to that object in separate array

          yourMutableArr.append("scannedString") // which are scanned 
                                                 recently

        2. reload tableview
           [yourTblView reloadData];

        3. In cellForRowAtIndexPath compare that barcodes with datasource array's barcode 

          let strBarcode: String = dict["barcode"][indexPath.row]
             if yourMutableArr.contains(strBarcode) {
              //addNewItem
                      cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
             }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that i can think of to achieve what you want.

```
//First
let filteredArray = dataArray.filter{$0["barcode"]!.contains("8901058847857")}

var tempArray = [Int]()

for dict in filteredArray{

   tempArray.append(dataArray.index{$0 == dict}!)
}

//this will have the appropriate rows that you want selected based on your initial and non filtered array   
print(tempArray)
```

Now all you have to do is try and figure out how to use this in your approach. The `tempArray` contains the indexes of the rows to select that matches your requirement. Now all you have to do is call the `UITableView`'s `selectRowMethod` and pass in the `indexPath` of the rows you have now

If all you want to do is to select the rows based on the condition and you aren't using the *filteredArray*, then there is no point in adding the elements that match your criteria in another array. You should use the following approach.

```
//Second approach
var index = 0
var tempArray = [Int]()

for dict in dataArray{

    if (dict["barcode"]?.contains("8901058847857"))!{

        //Or just select the row at this index value
        tempArray.append(index)
    }

    index += 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tableview is populated according to the array in a sequencial manner then, you can do this in the else block : **Find the index of the last object of the filtered item in the main item**. that should fetch you the indexpath.row of the tableview, which has the cell according to the array DS. You can fetch the cell by `cellForRowAtIndexPath` by providing the index of the array and getting the cell, then you can turn the selection of the cell and reload the indexpath.

Currently I am not in my mac, hence i couldnt write the code, but I explained the logic in finding it. Hope this helps.